# jquery traversing element for position

Tags: jquery, text, alignment

```
for (i=1; i <= 3; i++) {
   var larg = $("parallax-section-" + i).find('.testo-parallax').width();
   var largPa = larg / 2;
   var largParallax = "-" + largPa;
   $("parallax-section-" + i).find('.testo-parallax').css("margin-left",  largParallax);
}
```

HTML

```
<section class="slide parallax-section-2" >
   <h6 class="testo-parallax">Il weeb asdf asss dasdf ss.</h6>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.testo-parallax {
   font-size: 80px;
   color: #fff;
   font-weight: 600;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left:50%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   margin-top: -40px;
}
```

I want to center from left the text (.testo-parallax) in the section(.parallax-section). I have three sections and i want to check the width to take the half off width margin-left and -

Comment: You could put each section in a div, then just center the parallax-section-X within the div. Is that doable?

Comment: parallax-section-x is the container. I used text-align center to parallax-section-x to solve the problem! thank u for the hint anyway